# Measuring link quality between two machines

Tags: algorithm, sockets, networking, network-programming

Are there some standard methods(libraries) for measuring quality of link/connection between two computers.

This results would be used to improve routing logic. If connection condition is unacceptable stop data transfer to that computer and initiate alternative route for that transfer. It looks like Skype has some of this functionality.

I was thinking to establish several continuous testing streams that can show bandwidth problems, and some kind of ping-pong messaging logic to show latency values.

Comment: What kind of routing logic would you provide at the host-level?  Are you talking about routing to various servers in a pool, or using something like IP source-routing?

Comment: I am talking about routing to other available servers in a pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Link Reliability

I usually use a continuous traceroute (i.e. [mtr](http://www.bitwizard.nl/mtr/)) for isolating unreliable links; but for your purposes, you could start with average ping statistics as @recursive mentioned.  Migrate to more complicated things (like a UDP/TCP echo protocol) if you find that ICMP is getting blocked too often by client firewalls in the path.

### Bandwidth / Delay Estimation

For bandwidth and delay estimation, [yaz](https://bitbucket.org/jsommers/yaz/src) provides a low-bandwidth algorithm to estimate throughput / delay along the path; it uses two different endpoints for measurement, so your client and servers will need to coordinate their usage.

Sally Floyd maintains a pretty good [list of bandwidth estimation tools](http://www.icir.org/models/tools.html) that you may want to check out if yaz isn't what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is good for testing latency, but not bandwidth.